# Embed external application under Windows

Tags: windows, qt, embed, external

I have a Windows desktop application that I want to add some functionality to. Unfortunately the source code is not available, but it has a COM API.

So, my desire is to embed this application in my own window (with menus, toolbar, etc) and link events through the COM API.

How do you suggest I embed one application within another? 
(I had intended to use the Qt toolkit but it only supports embedding applications on Linux.)

thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a good way in Windows. Perhaps you can have your new application be an 'always on top' window mostly transparent and match the sizing and positioning of the 'embedded' application. This is probably easiest done with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveQt for this - which allows both embedding Qt components inside ActiveX clients as well as hosting ActiveX components inside Qt applications. See also

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/activeqt.html

Comment: unfortunately the application I am trying to embed is not an ActiveX component. Additionally, ActiveQt is not available for the open source license.